# Efficiently Read Images from Google Cloud Storage folder using Python PIL

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, python-imaging-library, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I want to read all the images in a GCS Folder (jpeg or png) efficiently.

I used the simple sequential read but it is very slow.

```
from gcsfs import GCSFileSystem
from PIL import Image

gcs = GCSFileSystem(project=PROJECT, token=ADC_JSON_PATH)
image_gcspaths = gcs.ls(GCS_FOLDER)

is_image_path = lambda p: p.endswith('.jpeg') or p.endswith('.png')
image_gcspaths = [
  image_gcspath for image_gcspath in image_gcspaths if is_img_path(is_image_path)
]

images = []
for image_gcspath in image_gcspaths:
    image = Image.open(gcs.open(image_gcspath, 'rb'))
    image = image.convert('RGB')
    images.append(image)

return images
```

Is there a faster way to do this using asyncio?
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202886/gcsfs-async-interface-does-not-seem-to-be-working-error-using-simple-example) states GCS does not support asyncio.

If that is the case then what is the fastest way to read all the images in a GCS bucket?

Comment: Maybe you can use a multithreading pool - somewhat akin to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66291332/2836621

Comment: The term `very slow` means nothing. It depends on what is slow. One HTTP data transfer typically consumes 25% to 100% of available network bandwidth. The slower your network connection the higher that percentage is.  The Google Cloud Storage Python SDK does not provide parallel downloads of multiple objects. You will need to write that functionality yourself or select a different library. However, make sure you know what you are optimizing else you will have no or little improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publishing this as community wiki for other's sake.

---

As mentioned by @John Hanley:

> The term very slow means nothing. It depends on what is slow. One HTTP data transfer typically consumes 25% to 100% of available network bandwidth. The slower your network connection the higher that percentage is. The Google Cloud Storage Python SDK does not provide parallel downloads of multiple objects. You will need to write that functionality yourself or select a different library. However, make sure you know what you are optimizing else you will have no or little improvement.

---

You can check this link for references:

- [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)
- [Python Client for Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest)

Comment: OK
So GCS SDK does not provide any functionality for multiple file download and I should I'll just do something simple like MultiThreading.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that's the case - I assumed I just couldn't find it in the docs. 

Why wouldn't Google provide such a common and important functionality? Download via. gsutil (gsutil -m cp -r GCS_FOLDER LOCAL_PATH) is insanely well parallelized it should be easy to do the same for the SDK